# Redirect output of Laravel installer

Tags: php, laravel, bash, composer-php

When I create a new project using the Laravel installer, the output always goes to my terminal, even when I redirect STDOUT and/or STDERR to a file.

For example:

```
$ .composer/vendor/bin/laravel new test > ~/installer.out
Crafting application...
Loading composer repositories with package information
...
```

And:

```
$ .composer/vendor/bin/laravel new test 2> ~/installer.out
Crafting application...
Loading composer repositories with package information
...
```

How can I capture the installer output to a file?

NOTE: this is NOT a bash redirection issue. Somehow, the Laravel installer is writing output to the terminal without using STDOUT or STDERR.

Comment: This is not a simple STDOUT/STDERR redirection problem. The question is specific to the Laravel installer. The output of the Laravel installer is not going to either stream, as demonstrated in my two examples.

Comment: The Laravel installer is not a bash command. It is a PHP script that launches an entire Laravel App framework.

Answer (score -1):

According to [this awesome list](https://askubuntu.com/a/731237/638079), you should probably use `&>` to redirect just to files.

Comment: Downvoted as this is not a simple STDOUT/STDERR redirection problem. The question is specific to the Laravel installer. The output of the Laravel installer is not going to either stream, as demonstrated in my two examples.